# Python NLP: How to map tokenized text back into original structures?

Tags: python, list, matrix, nlp, text-mining

Objective: Vectorize tokenized text to create term document matrix that enables NLP analysis on unstructured text data. Prediction and text classification will be a big part of the analysis, so being able to associate a label/class with each text is crucial. To this end, I need the term document matrix to be structured such that each row represents one text and each column represents one of the words that appears in the entire corpus. The text's class/label will also be a vector in the matrix.

Problem: Each record in the text is represented as an item in a list (the first record is the first item in the list, the second record is the second item in the list, and so on). Tokenizing the contents of every record in the list and generating a huge list of every word is easy. My problem is that after tokenization I'm unable to retain the original list structure and map each of the tokens with their record from the original list. This renders vectorization impossible.

To illustrate:

```
record_one = 'I like ham. I also like pineapple.'
record_two = 'I love cheese. I enjoy tomato sauce and dough too.'
record_three = 'Hence, I dig Hawaiian pizza. And beer.'
recordList = [record_one, record_two, record_three]
```

Results (three records in list, each with two sentences):

```
['I like ham. I also like pineapple.', 'I love cheese. I enjoy tomato sauce and dough too.', 'Hence, I dig Hawaiian pizza. And beer.']
```

Tokenizing:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
wordList= []
for r in recordList:
    temp = word_tokenize(r)
    for token in temp:
        wordList.append(token)
```

Results (one huge list of every word in recordList):

```
['I', 'like', 'ham.', 'I', 'also', 'like', 'pineapple', '.', 'I', 'love', 'cheese.', 'I', 'enjoy', 'tomato', 'sauce', 'and', 'dough', 'too', '.', 'Hence', ',', 'I', 'dig', 'Hawaiian', 'pizza.', 'And', 'beer', '.']
```

Here's where I'm stuck. Vectorizing at this point gives me a 28x18 matrix, when what I need is a 3x18 matrix. I need to somehow map each term to its record in recordList to give me the 3x18 matrix, but I'm not sure how to do that. I know there's something obvious I'm missing.

I'm new to Python and NLP, so I'm trying to keep things as simple as possible. This means using lists, creating loops to work over those lists, and list comprehensions. I know there are other modules and functions that can do this (scikit), but I'm trying to force myself to use fundamental Python data structures to improve my understanding of the language. If it's possible to create a solution using a basic Python data structure that would be awesome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you don't have the word set for each document. That's why you end up with a 28x18 matrix instead of 3x18.

Here's a Python based approach that you can try -

```
In [22]: doc_words = [set() for _ in recordList]
In [24]: for index, record in enumerate(recordList):
    token_generator = word_tokenize(record)
    for token in token_generator:
        doc_words[index].add(token)
In [28]: all_words = {word for doc_word_set in doc_words for word in doc_word_set}
In [31]: all_words_list = list(all_words)
In [32]: [[1 if word in doc_word_set else 0 for word in all_words_list] for doc_word_set in doc_words]
Out[32]: 
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]
In [48]: all_words_list
Out[48]: 
['enjoy',
 'cheese',
 'and',
 'love',
 'like',
 'Hawaiian',
 'I',
 'too',
 'dig',
 ',',
 '.',
 'And',
 'also',
 'beer',
 'dough',
 'tomato',
 'pineapple',
 'Hence',
 'pizza',
 'sauce',
 'ham']
```

Explanation of some steps -

22: We use `doc_words` to track the words in each document. We initialize it as a list of sets; each set for one document.

24: We populate the sets of words

28: We collect the set of all words

31: We convert the set into list, so that the order of words is fixed

32: We print out the matrix; we iterate over each document's word set, and then test presence of each word in the document's word set.

The output shows the word's in the order in `all_words_list`. You can consider sorting all_words_list in 31 for a cleaner output.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer()
words_csm = cv.fit_transform(records)
words_csm.todense()

matrix([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```